# Is there a recommended way to seed a database on shared hosting with code first

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, shared-hosting, seeding

Every time I deploy and MVC site to a live host (usually shared hosting) I have a load of trouble seeding the database initially.

I keep trying various things and eventually it works, but it's not unusual to take  a couple of hours of trial and error.

I create the DB on the shared host. Then I launch the app with `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`.  It often then gives me the unending 'loading' page.

I might run the app again, and perhaps it has created the DB tables, but not populated any of them.

Using any of the `DropCreateDatabase` options doesn't work - it doesn't have permission (presumably because on a shared host).

Rinse, lather, repeat, until finally it seems to work!

*Is there a recommended way to create and seed the DB on a shared host?  Do you have any recommendations for making this task easier?*

**Update**

In Gobal.asax:

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
```

In the Initializer:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        var dataSeeder = new DataSeeder(db);
        dataSeeder.SeedAll();
        base.Seed(db);
    }
}
```

Seeding is just standard code, like: `db.Objects.AddRange(List<Object>)`

Comment: show some code, specifically the code where you define your Database Initializer and the code where you are calling your `Seed()` method.

Comment: I think the code is alright (famous last words). It all works fine during development, it's just when I switch the DB to one on the shared hosting that I have trouble

Comment: this might be a bit ignorant of me, but that sounds more like a connectivity issue with the host. I can't think of any reason why seeding on host vs local would be different at the .NET level...unless there's more to this story. when you say it eventually works, is there some some consistency to steps taken that make it finally work?

Comment: Yea I would have thought it would have been the same.  I've tried a few different hosts, and always have similar issues. That's why I wondered if there was some thing I was missing, or doing wrong. When it eventually works, it is with a freshly created DB and using the `CreateIfNotExists` option.  (But why that  setup doesn't work the first time, I don't understand).  It's normally 2 or 3 times before it works.